# RESTEasy giving null value as form params in a @DELETE method

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I am working on designing restful web service API using REASTEasy. I have a workflow where I have to delete multiple items in a resource. The web service signature looks something like this

```
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/directories/{directoryname}/documents")
public Response deleteDocuments(@FormParam("documentnames")final String documents, @PathParam("directoryname")final String directoryName)
```

I am making following request

```
DELETE /directories/1234/documents HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 45c0094f-1853-5710-2201-a1102a6acef0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

documentnames=test
```

But when the method is invoked the form parameter "documentnames" is having the value as `null` even when I am passing its value as `test` as shown in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review your annotations again:

```
@Path("/directories/{directoryname}/documents")
public Response deleteDocuments(@FormParam("documentnames")final String documents, @PathParam("directoryname")final String directoryName)
```

`@PathParam("directoryname")`  refers to `{directoryname}` in `@Path` definition while `@FormParam("documentnames")` should get data from form request. However your perform `HTTP DELETE` without form parameters. At least I do not see them in capture that your have sent.

Did you probably want to send directories as a path parameter too?

Comment: form parameters are there as `documentnames=test` in the end of the request.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not see it. I think (almost sure) that delete method does not support body at all. Take a look on this article: http://amundsen.com/examples/put-delete-forms/. It *suggest* to add such functionality to delete and put methods. So, you should use URL path parameters for delete only.